# Assigning multiple methods to an application in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I have now officially spent all day trying to assign a variable in JavaScript!
Forgive me for asking this same question 4 different ways, but here's what I started out with this morning, and this works. I just need to add a second method to it now.

```
Application = {};
(function() {
    var closure = {};

    Application.myFirstMethod = function() {
        if (arguments.length) {
            closure = arguments[0];
        } else {
            return closure;
        }
    }
})();

Application.myFirstMethod(3.14);
result = Application.myFirstMethod();
log(result);
```

So my question is: and please be patient with me, if I add `mySecondMethod` to `Application`, then how do I keep the value of `arguments[0]` without using the variable that is currently called closure?

Comment: I suppose I could copy/paste the IIFE, but what do I do if I need to share variables across methods?

Comment: Define another variable..?

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't seem right. myFirstClosure and mySecondClosure?

Comment: What is `local` supposed to be?

Comment: Well, `closure` is an object, so why not declare `closure.varFromFirstMethod = arguments[0];` and `closure.varFromSecondMethod = arguments[0];`

Comment: You're just trying to define a public setter and getter with a private backing field?

Comment: Sorry about `local`. Here: I'll change it to the number 3.14.

Comment: Never heard of a private backing field.  I must be doing it wrong. But yes, I'm trying to define a getter and a setter.

Comment: +1 closure.varFromFirstMethod.  Probably not "the right" way to do it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I figured out.  I probably need to use the word `new` somewhere though.

```
Application = {};
(function() {
    Application.myFirstMethod = FirstMethod();
    Application.mySecondMethod = SecondMethod();

    function FirstMethod() {
        var closure = {};
        return function(myArgument) {
            if (arguments.length) {
                closure.result = arguments[0]; // myArgument
            } else {
                return closure.result;
            }
        }
    }
    function SecondMethod() {
        var closure = {};
        return function(myArgument) {
            if (arguments.length) {
                closure.result = arguments[0]; // myArgument
            } else {
                return closure.result;
            }
        }
    }
})();


Application.myFirstMethod(3.14);
result = Application.myFirstMethod();
log(result);

Application.mySecondMethod(2013);
result = Application.mySecondMethod();
log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this, it defines a function that takes a string and returns a getter/setter function. The string is used to indicate what property to get/set the value as in `variables`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hnKt/)

```
Application = {};
(function() {
    var variables = {};

    Application.myFirstMethod = makeGetterSetter('myFirst');
    Application.mySecondMethod = makeGetterSetter('mySecond');

    function makeGetterSetter(name) {
        return function () {
            if (arguments.length) {
                variables[name] = arguments[0];
            } else {
                return variables[name];
            }
        };
    }
})();

Application.myFirstMethod(4);
result1 = Application.myFirstMethod();
Application.mySecondMethod(5);
result2 = Application.mySecondMethod();
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

If you wanted to have a getter or setter with custom logic in it before either event then it would be easiest to just define them separately. Stick with the `this[property]` pattern to keep all your fields in one spot.

```
Application.myCustomMethod = function() {
    if (arguments.length) {
        // some logic
        variables['custom'] = arguments[0];
    } else {
        // some logic
        return variables['custom'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting.  Now, the need for two methods is because they will each have their own logic, so your solution to build 1 makeGetterSetter method is a bit off the mark, but I think I see where I've fallen short.  I need to return a function which returns a value.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish, it seems as though you're trying to bend JavaScript to follow a pattern it isn't designed for. Adding more context to the question would be beneficial as you may be going in the wrong direction.

Comment: OK, thanks Daniel!  I want to write an application with a bunch of getters and setters.  app.myFirstMethod(1) sets the value, app.myFirstMethod() gets the value.

Comment: And the getters and setters won't just be straight getters and setters, but have custom logic?

Comment: Well, it's hard to predict the future.  Potentially, they could have custom logic, yes.  Unless I would put the logic somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are searching for adding properties to objects, in the Prototype-Oriented Programming Language sense of the term; just use the "this" object, which stands for the current calling context, and which will be set to your Application object when calling the methods:

```
Application = {};
(function() {

  Application.myFirstMethod = function() {
    if (arguments.length) {
        this.foo = arguments[0];
    } else {
        return this.foo;
    }
  };
  Application.mySecondMethod = function() {
    if (arguments.length) {
        this.bar = arguments[0];
    } else {
        return this.bar;
    }
  };
})();

Application.myFirstMethod(3.14);
console.log(Application.myFirstMethod());

Application.mySecondMethod(2097);
console.log(Application.mySecondMethod());
console.log(Application.myFirstMethod());
```

Comment: But I don't want to use 2 different variable names to hold the closures.  I want to be able to use the same variable name in both functions and have JavaScript keep them in the closure scope.